# ssh config per dns domains

Tags: linux, ssh

I have two platforms with many servers I want to connect to via ssh.

I have in resolv.conf

```
search domain1.net domain2.org
```

So I only have the machine name to type for ssh.

**I want to have an ssh config per domain**:

- user admin for every machine of domain1.net
- user root for every machine of domain2.org

How can I achieve that ?

**Host**, **Hostname** directives seems to only works with what you type in the ssh command, not what is expanded with DNS suffixes

Comment: I don't think this is going to be possible without some significant code changes. Handling of `search` is done in a library and the `ssh` code doesn't see the full name at any point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe OpenSSH CAN do canonicalization. Please have a look at the following options in ssh_config man page:

- CanonicalizeHostname
- CanonicalizeFallbackLocal
- CanonicalizeMaxDots
- CanonicalizePermittedCNAMEs
- Host
- Match with `canonical` option

Please note, this may require newer OpenSSH version than the one you have (I have 7.4p1).

Answer (score 0):

As kasperd said, this is not really possible.

Some workarounds:

- I just use some small shell variables to expand `$e` to `example.org` for things I don't access so often. Others are listed in `~/.ssh/config` anyway with a short name. You use it like so:

  ```
  ssh www.$e
  ```

  With this, you can use the standard `~/.ssh/config` method.
- Another option: Write a small wrapper script or shell function for ssh that catches the hostname and expands it, something like this:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  hn=`host $1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
  ssh $hn
  ```

  If you call it with `sshwrapper.sh www`, it will expand `www` to `www.example.org` and use this for `ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

backing what @sven said, a tiny bash function can do the same:

```
ssh() {
    declare h=$(host $1 | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
    command ssh $h
}
```

Put this somewhere in one of your sourced files, e.g. .profile, and it's always fixing up the name from the search order in /etc/resolv.conf

Answer (score 0):

another approach that could come handy to others utilizes (relatively) new ssh_config features that allow for include files and even the include can be conditional.

I'm just going to share an obfuscated example from my config that tests that if

- my phone is connected over USB **and**
- I don't have another network connection (I don't have a default route)

Then it will include another file that routes some ssh things thru my phone

```
Match exec "[ -e /dev/serial/by-id/usb-SAMSUNG_SAMSUNG_Android_XXXXXXXX-if01 ] && ! ip route| grep -q ^default"
    Include blahblah_termux.ssh
```

You should be able to have a ~/.ssh/domain1.ssh & ~/.ssh/domain2.ssh and include those based on a Match test (your test would obviously be customized)